# Where to create classes dynamically? Within Object or global namespace?

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

I am creating non-namespaced classes dynamically.

I have seen an example where this creation is done within the Object class:

```
class Object

  for elem in ARRAY
    sub_class = Object.const_set(elem.to_s.camelize, Class.new(SuperClass))

    sub_class.class_eval do
      def initialize(*args, &block)
        ...
        super *args, &block
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My Questions:

- Would you also evaluate this within the context of Object?
- Where is the difference from creating classes in global namespace?
- Any advantages or disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. Upon some experimentation, calling `SomeConstant.const_set` from different contexts doesn't make any difference, so calling it inside the `class Object` block is the same as defining it in the toplevel namespace.

Furthermore: everything in the global namespace is implicitely defined in the Object class, so it is actually redundant. The only advantage I can see [over defining it in a different class, or in the Kernel module] is that the constant will be available to all classes, and the lookup chain will look at the `Object` class before the `Kernel` module.

Comment: Ah, okay.

Regarding your last sentence: my question was whether defining it in `Object` is advantageous compared to toplevel namespace. So it will be available to all classes anyway. 

Thus, the bottom line is: *There is no difference* (as global namespace means implictly Object namespace).